# Mysql subquery alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the unknown column error when I use subquery alias in where clause:

```
SELECT name, 
(SELECT id FROM category c2 WHERE c2.parent_id=23) children 
FROM category c1 WHERE c1.id IN children;
```

Can anybody tell why this code is not working?

Comment: There are many reasons why your query is not working.  How about starting with sample data and desired results, so we have some idea of what you want to do.

Comment: You cannot reference a subquery that is in your SELECT clause in your WHERE clause. Tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Do it the other way around:

```
SELECT name, 
FROM category c1 
WHERE c1.id IN (SELECT id FROM category c2 WHERE c2.parent_id=23);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the query without subselect

```
 select a.name, b.id as children  
 from category as a
 inner join category b on ( a.c1.id = b.id  and b.parent_id = 23 );
```